# About Codd's theorem

Tags: applications

I was learning about databases and I have developed a rough idea that the design of databases has got quite a lot to do with mathematics. The most common and probably advanced form of databases are relational databases. The very beginning of its definition in standard textbooks say that it is a mathematical model devised by Codd. On searching I got to know that it is based on Codd's theorem which posits and provides a mathematical definition for the "*expressive power* . I would like to know  which branch of mathematics does codd theorem belong to and what other areas of mathematics does databse design pertain to (or will possibly pertain to in future). 
Hope it's not a broad question to be closed . Eagerly waiting for reply , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Codd theorem stems from mathematical logic (more precisely, relational calcululs). The notion of expressive power is particularly relevant in the context of finite model theory and descriptive complexity. Database theory has also fruitful interactions with automata theory (e.g. verification technics for semi structured data) and algorithms and complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply after this many months :) Could you throw some more light on model's theory interactions and database design .